# Evaluate a string as PHP code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, eval

I have a string that I want to have PHP read as a piece of code. The reason is that I want to build the set of instructions for PHP in advance, and then execute it later on. Currently I have:

```
$string = '$this->model_db->get_results()';
```

And the desired result is:

```
$string2 = $this->model_db->get_results();
```

Comment: If `eval` is a solution for your task - you definitely doing it wrong

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have a variable variable/function, but cannot have variable method chains. you can however create a method chain using variable variables/functions.

Check this page of the php documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

it shows the usage of using strings as object or method names. using eval may lead to security vulnerabilities depending on the source of your data.

```
$var1 = 'model_db';
$var2 = 'get_results';

$this->$var1->$var2();
```

Comment: although to be honest, there is probably a better solution to what you are trying to accomplish without using either mentioned method.

Comment: I'm going to tick this one seeing as its a lot more simple and probably more effeciant. Thanks to both for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want PHP's [eval function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), which executes a string containing PHP code.  For example:

```
// Now
$get_results = '$this->model_db->get_results(' . intval($id) . ');';

// Later
eval($get_results);
```

However, ***eval is usually a bad idea***.  That is to say, there are much better ways to do things you might think to do with `eval`.

In the example above, you have to make sure `$this` is in scope in the code calling `eval`.  This means if you try to `eval($get_results)` in a completely different part of the code, you might get an error  about `$this` or `$this->model_db` not existing.

A more robust alternative would be to create an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (available in PHP 5.3 and up):

```
// Now
$that = $this;
$get_results = function() use ($that, $id) {
    return $that->model_db->get_results($id);
};

// Later
call_user_func($get_results);
```

But what if `$this` isn't available right now?  Simple: make it a function parameter:

```
// Now
$get_results = function($that) use ($id) {
    return $that->model_db->get_results($id);
};

// Later
call_user_func($get_results, $this);
```

Answer (score 1):

**http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php**

```
<?php
    $string = 'cup';
    $name = 'coffee';
    $str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
    echo $str. "\n";
    eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
    echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

Or in your case:

```
<?php
    $string = "\$string2 = \$this->model_db->get_results();";
    // ... later ...
    eval($string);
    // Now $string2 is equal to $this->model_db->get_results()
?>
```

Comment: @user971824 yes, eval works, but is bad practice. see my answer for an alternative.